# insert-select session customer

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I want to select one row of a table and insert in another existing table.
(I use `php` and `MySql`. The two tables have the same columns except the id and the timestamp)

I try to make a cart. I want that when someone pays, select all the products of that client and that session from "carret" and insert into "comandes".

The insert - select works if I say for instance `WHERE session=4");`
This works too: `echo session_id();` So I can get the session
But this two things does not work together. I don't understand the problem. What is wrong with my where condition?

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comandes (session,client,producte,preu_comanda,quantitat)
         SELECT session,client,producte,preu_unitat,quantitat
         FROM carret
         WHERE session='".session_id()."'");
```

I tried too without success: `WHERE client='$_SESSION[client]'`

Comment: And what is the mysql_error which is returned from your php ?

If there is no error try selecting that row from the DB without INSERTING it ...  be sure that your SELECT is getting anything

Comment: It gives no error. The select works because if I use all the code but I put WHERE session=4 (or the number of any other customer) it works

Comment: Then echo that $query, copy the code and test it at PHPMYADMIN > or what ever you use to control your Mysql databases. 
! NOTE > mysql_query will be deprecated its better for you to use mysqli or PDO ..  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the problem with a simple ";" at the end.  I post it because it could help to other php beginners like me.

This works:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comandes (id_carret,session,client,producte,preu_comanda,quantitat)
             SELECT id,session,client,producte,preu_unitat,quantitat
             FROM carret
             WHERE session='".session_id()."'");
```

This does not works!! The problem is with the final ";" if after that there is the "or die ...":

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comandes (id_carret,session,client,producte,preu_comanda,quantitat)
             SELECT id,session,client,producte,preu_unitat,quantitat
             FROM carret
             WHERE session='".session_id()."'");

or die("error:".mysql_error());
```

This works. Now I see that, if there is the final "or die..." I should remove the previous ";"

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comandes (id_carret,session,client,producte,preu_comanda,quantitat)
             SELECT id,session,client,producte,preu_unitat,quantitat
             FROM carret
             WHERE session='".session_id()."'")

or die("error:".mysql_error());
```